# How to resolve OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'Service has been disabled for this account.'?

Tags: api, google-chrome, scope

How can I resolve

```
OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'Service has been disabled for this account.'
```

?

I have a Chrome extension that requires a "See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets" sensitive scope. I think maybe some companies block apps with this and this is what is triggering the error.

Do you know if this is the case and how to resolve / maybe do further authentication to remove this error? I was thinking maybe registering on restricted scope .....but honestly not sure if that'll work

I registered sensitive scope but it still seems to be triggering an error for some folks. I think it is a company issue & wondering if others have had this problem and if there's a way to get around this

Comment: Are you a black hat hacker?

Comment: Lol nah I feel like I'm missing a registration here or something. Tool I'm building is a sheets productivity extension that for it to run requires access levels noted above...but it's not being allowed for some company accounts